# Accessing data from a loop on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a for loop in the controller and I can't access that data coming this loop in view blade. my code is as follows:

My for-loop in the controller:

```
$history = bookings::select('*')->where(['costumer_id'=>$id])->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->orderBy('time', 'DESC')->get();

        $data=[];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($history); $i++){
            $b_id = $history[$i]->id;
            $service = $history[$i]->service;
            $time = $history[$i]->time;
            $date = $history[$i]->date;
            $status = $history[$i]->service_status;
            $s_id = $history[$i]->specialist_id;
            $user = User::with('profile')->find($s_id);

            array_push($data,['id'=>$b_id, 'date'=>$date." - ".$time, 'name'=>$user->name." ".$user->profile->lastname, 'service'=>$service, 'status'=>$status]);
        }
```

When i test if the data exist using `return $data;` i get the following response:

```
[{"id":45,"date":"2020-07-21 - 10:00","name":"John Doe","service":"service 1","status":"complete"},{"id":44,"date":"2020-07-21 - 06:00","name":"Jane Doe","service":"service 18","status":"complete"},{"id":40,"date":"2020-07-18 - 06:00","name":"Foo foo","service":"service 6","status":"pending"},{"id":42,"date":"2020-07-17 - 06:00","name":"Hello world","service":"service 1","status":"complete"}]
```

And when i passing the data to view using `return view('admin.history')->with('data', $data);` i get the following error:

```
Trying to get property 'date' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\history_beta\resources\views\admin\costumer.blade.php)
```

Here is how my view blade code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Service Provider</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Service</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($data as $hist)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $hist->date }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $hist->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $hist->service }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $hist->status }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Please assist in review my code and point-out where i'm loosing the data or what's causing the error.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that your `$data` is an associative array? Perhaps, you want to do `$data['date']` instead of `$data->date`?

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm